# 2008 Sever Randomly reboots

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell, hp-proliant

I'm out of ideas here. We have a 2008 Server that keeps rebooting 2-3 times a day at completely random times with an "Unexpected Shutdown" event. There are no Dumps, no events leading to it just like it loses power then comes back online. I ran a Diagnostic of the power supply and it has had continuous power for months. In addition, the temperature of the processors are maxing out at 40 degrees Celsius. Anyone have any ideas how to figure out why this is restarting all the time? This is a DMZed Web server so it doesn't do too much process wise. Here are the specs:

```
Host Name:                 ~~~
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 
OS Version:                6.1.7600 N/A Build 7600
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Server
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Windows User
Registered Organization:   
Product ID:                ~~~
Original Install Date:     5/27/2010, 4:25:47 PM
System Boot Time:          2/14/2011, 5:35:01 PM
System Manufacturer:       HP
System Model:              ProLiant DL380 G6
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5 GenuineIntel ~1586 Mhz
BIOS Version:              HP P62, 8/16/2010
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     4,086 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,775 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  8,170 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 6,691 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    1,479 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
```

Comment: Is it happening at the same times? Is it every single day? What does the server do? What users does it have?

Comment: Completely random times every day. No users, its a DMZed Web Server. (I'll update above)

Comment: what HW brand any warnings in managment cards?

Comment: @Jacob All Dell management items are green. Ran all diagnostics as well with no issues.

Comment: Memory issues? If you have several memory modules try removing one by one to see if you get rid of your crashes.

Comment: Dell management? I thought this was HP?

Comment: Oops yeah, Brain Malfunction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a small issue with a specific run of the HP ProLiant DL380 G6 servers tied to the power management unit.

Please see:
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?locale=en_US&objectID=c01955503

A limited number of ProLiant DL380 G6-based servers and StorageWorks products (listed in the Scope section below) configured with a system board that has a revision number earlier than "0S" may reboot unexpectedly. During the reboot, the following message will be recorded in the Integrated Lights-Out 2 (iLO 2) Event Log:

Server Reset, Server Power Removed, Server Power Restored

When this occurs, no hardware errors will be logged, no events will be captured in the Integrated Management Log (IML), and the system will not execute an Automatic Server Recovery (ASR); however, the operating system log will indicate that an unexpected reboot occurred.

`SCOPE
A limited number of ProLiant DL380 G6 and ProLiant DL380 G6 Carrier Grade servers that are configured with a system board with a revision level earlier than 0S, that were shipped prior to 16 November 2009, and that have a serial number earlier than XXX 947 XXXX.`

This impacted a lot of the first DL380 G6 systems I installed. It will require the firmware update at the link above and a power off, remove power cables, then power on to activate. Check your serial number range against the notice.

Comment: Wow, that describes the situation perfectly. I'm going the check the serial now. +1 for that find.

Comment: Was the serial number within the range?

Comment: it sure was. We flashed it but it still didn't work. An HP tech will replace the systemboard per that article tomorrow. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Great call Ed!!

Answer (score 3):

It's a HP G6, there's a good chance it's still under warranty, it sounds like a CPU/chipset/memory/motherboard issue, get HP out to look at it. It's almost certainly not a software issue.

If you have another identical server swap out there disks, see if the problem stays with the server or the disks.

Comment: Sadly, we do not have an identical machine. We do run disk image backups for this client with shadow protect, though, perhaps I'll load up VMWare and mount it's image to see if it crashes.

Comment: you were technically correct as well though the other answer was better :) it was the MoBo, manufacture Defect as per ewwhite. Thanks though +1

Comment: Totally agree, his was a great answer - glad you're sorted.